# Job seeker enhanced user card

Tags: feature-request, jobs, profile-page, user-card

I'd like to see an option to enhance the standard user card in stackoverflow to indicate that I am looking for work and that I have a resume posted on the careers site (similar to as linked-in).

For exampple, here is my standard user card:
[image]

and here is my job seeker enhanced user card:
[image]

Answer (score 5):

This seems like a good idea, but I think seeing the icon should be optional. The vast majority of people browsing Stack Overflow aren't looking for people to interview and showing it to everyone would be distracting, especially if more icons are added over time.

Comment: I agree with your commanet on making this feature optional; that said we need two options, one to indicate someone is looking for work, and two to show people who are looking for work.  In either case both need to be off by default to reduce noise.  Thanks for the interesting comment.

Comment: They already know whether someone's looking for work by if they have paid to be visible in searches.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say it generates too much noise for too little benefit (99% of people interacting with you on SO won't be hiring). A note in the profile, together with a contact E-Mail address (and a CV on careers) should do well already.

Comment: You make a good point about the noise this feature may add; especially if more specialty flags get added.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's unnecessary. If an employer needed to hire somebody, they would go to [careers.stackoverflow.com](http://careers.stackoverflow.com), not [stackoverflow.com](http://www.stackoverflow.com). You can mention that you're looking for work on your user profile, but remember that your CV on the careers site is already linked to your Stack Overflow account, so they will be able to see what skills and capabilities you have.

Comment: My idea centers around a using one to do a bit of cross-promotion. Thanks for your comment.